# Solution to an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The general solution to the equation $y''+by'+cy=0$ approaches to $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity if

- $b$ is negative $c$ is positive
- $b$ is positive $c$ is negative
- $b$ is positive $c$ is positive
- $b$ is negative $c$ is negative

Comment: The first bullet has an $a$ in it.  Is this supposed to be a question?  What is it and where are you stuck?

Comment: @B.Goddard maybe the reason for $a=1$ is that the second order term does not vanish.

Comment: @Cuteboy  There's no $a$ in the equation.

Comment: @B.Goddard no, but I mean that one can always rescale the equation if $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Perhaps you are reciting a multiple choice question here, but this is not the sort of content that Math.SE seeks to accumulate.  Please review [ask] and state a question in your own words.

Comment: @Cuteboy I'm not talking about the equation, but about the first bullet point, which, before the edit, had an $a$ in it.  He has fixed it now.

Comment: @B.Goddard ok, i also saw that^^, just automatically corrected in mind

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** to find the solutions of this differential equation, replace $y''$ by $r^2$ and $y'$ by $r$, and solve the quadratic polynomial
$$r^2 + br + c = 0$$
to find the roots $r_1,r_2$.

The solution $y(x)$ of the differential equation is then given by
$$y(x) = Ae^{r_1x} + Be^{r_2x}$$
if $r_1 \neq r_2$, and otherwise by
$$y(x) = Ae^{r_1x} + Bxe^{r_1x}.$$
Note that if $r_1,r_2$ are complex, they are necessarily complex conjugates of the form $\alpha \pm \beta i$, and you can rewrite the solution as
$$y(x) = e^{\alpha x}(A\cos(\beta x) + B \sin (\beta x)).$$

The signs of $b$ and $c$ will determine the signs of $r_1$ and $r_2$, which in turn determine the behaviour of your function as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I dont really think the signs of $b$ and $c$ really matter, but indeed the term $b^2-4c$.

Comment: @Cuteboy The discriminant determines which of the three solutions you get, but the signs of $r_1$ and $r_2$ are determined by $-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}$.  And, if the signs didn't matter, the question itself wouldn't make much sense, would it?

Comment: you are right, but for me the question just does not look appropriate, since in fact the roots play an essential role but the sign itself.

Comment: @Cuteboy Let's assume $\sqrt{b^2-4c} > 0$. If $c > 0$ then $\sqrt{b^2-4c} < |b|$. Then the sign of $b$ alone determines the signs of $r_1$ and $r_2$.  If on the other hand $c < 0$, then $\sqrt{b^2-4c} > |b|$ and $r_1$ and $r_2$ will have a different sign.

You can do this for other cases too, but in the end the signs of $b$ and $c$ will be decisive.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, but I mean that just looks uncomfortable for me since if one knows some fundamentals in ODE, one will always concern the roots themself but not really the signs of the constants...

Answer (score 1):

To seek a non-zero solution, put $y=e^{mx}$ ($m$ is arbitrary constant) in the given ODE

Then the auxiliary equation you get is $e^{mx}(m^2+bm+c)=0$

or $m^2+bm+c=0$ as $e^{mx}\neq 0$.

In case of real roots,what you want is that this quadratic  equation must not have a positive real root for which $b>0$ and $c>0$ (by Descarte's rule of signs) is sufficient.

In case no real root exists, even then you need the real part of the root to be negative for which you must have $b>0$.

In both cases, option $3$ is the best choice.